# Error list is not showing in visual studio 2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. When I am downloading svn copy of my project from server it gets downloaded. But when I open it it's showing me number of errors and warning. But it's not showing list of errors.

I thought that, net is corrupted thats why I uninstalled and installed again. Buts it's showing same result. In same case when I am creating new projects it's working fine. But when I downloaded svn copy then only I got error. I am not understanding what is exactly issue. I have also updated svn. Still getting same result.

Comment: Are you talking about the ‘Error List’? It's available under *View* > *Error List*.

Comment: yes i know that but under view also its not displaying.